# How to separate fragments to different files in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to develop an android app in android studio and I keep writing more and more fragments in the mainActivity class. My question is how to separate these to another file? Probably I am doing it in a wrong way and if so could somebody show me how should I do it?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
.
.
.
public static class PlaceholderFragment1 extends Fragment {...}
public static class PlaceholderFragment2 extends Fragment {...}
public static class PlaceholderFragment3 extends Fragment {...}
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since they are static inner classes, AndroidStudio can easily refactor these for you. Select `PlaceholderFragment1` (just put the text cursor on it) and press F6 (or right click the fragment name->refactor->move) and select `Move inner class [fragment name] to upper level', change the name and package if you want and hit refactor.

Having a static inner class for a Fragment is fine (will work technically), but if you want to reuse the fragment in another activity, best to refactor it out. Also, most people like to keep classes as small as possible, and if the function of the fragment is logically separate from the activity there is little reason to keep it as an inner class.

Comment: Thank you very much. Basically the previous answer was the same but with this one I could solve it literally in 3 clicks. Amazing man. Thank you again

Comment: This sir, is a beautiful thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You could without problem write them as separate classes in the same package and then just use them. Otherwise write them in a separate package and import them as any other class.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create a new class (new class file)

NOTE: You will ned to create a class like this for every fragment you have to define the fragment logic.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}
//logic here
}
```

Then you can use it in your MainActivity which extends FragmentActivity like:

```
MyFragment fragment= new MyFragment();
```

or if exists

```
fragment= (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
```

You can set your fragments to view with:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
```